# Is there a way to assign a default value as int8 to a pandas dataframe column in a single line?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

When assigning a default value for a new pandas dataframe columns, I noticed that the type is int64. To occupy less memory I converted to int8 with a second line. However I was wondering if there was a way to do it in as single line instead of two.

```
# Create new column with default value 1
df['reordered'] = 1
# Convert it from int64 to int8
df['reordered'] = df['reordered'].astype(int8)
```

Thank you for helping a neophyte

Comment: `df['reordered'] = np.int8(1)`?

Comment: @JohnGalt I was in the middle of posting this when I saw your comment come up :-)

Comment: @piRSquared - your solution with details will help :-)

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you for the quick help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1], columns=['A'])

df['B'] = np.int8(1)

df

   A  B
0  1  1
```

---

```
df.dtypes

A    int64
B     int8
dtype: object
```